# How to ensure source code matches an application?

Tags: software-design

Preword:
I have come across this issue in a made-up scenario. Imagine company X wishes to work with potentially sensitive data of their customers. How would they prove they only do what they claim to do?

Example: Company X wishes to match users with similar habits, without tampering with the data any further.

My partial solution:
Company X would release the source code of their application, which would confirm that the company only matches the data (and does not search for patterns, create personalised ads, etc.).

The remaining problem:
How does Company X prove that the released source code matches the code they are running? My requirements are that nobody should trust any instance, neither Company X nor any third-party. Simply hiring a third-party to "certify" Company X' practices is not a proof, simply another claim.

Side Note: Does it make a significant difference if the application does not need to be compiled before usage (e.g. PHP)?

Are there any solutions to this? Any "provable" method to ensure a certain source code is being run?

Comment: This might be better asked at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @sasfrog You might be right. I will do so tomorrow if it has not been moved until then

Comment: In your situation I think you are focused on the data more than the source code. How about you put all sensitive data into a DBMS and then ensure that the only manipulation of that data must go through the DBMS, where all queries may be logged and audited. Then you will always know what is being done, this is true whether you have source code or not

Comment: @Brandin this helps against manipulation in the database yes. But then again once they retrieved a record no one could stop them from storing it outside the dbms and then to do with the d ata what they want. And a read operation is nothing you could declare illegal because without the data you can't process the data.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure the binary matches the source is to compile it yourself or at least compare it to a binary you compiled yourself under the exact same circumstances.
But then again you have to do the same to every piece of software involved (the compiler could change the code, libraries could do something bad etc.).

Even if the software is not compiled the interpreter would have to be validated in this way because it interprets and runs the source (i.e. can modify it in any way it wants)

For your scenario the data could also be used and processed outside the specific software so their whole system would have to be audited and build in this way and then locked down. Choose your level of paranoia.

So the answer is not realistically without trusting someone. That's the idea behind signed packages in several Linux systems (including android) were some party like the developer or a repository  maintainer signs the binary to verify it's what he compiled (and matches the published source).

Also in the previous step with verifying the source: it's pretty easy to show that a program has a certain functionality but (most often) impossible to show that it doesn't have it.

So basically choose your own level of paranoia but if they are really after you, you are screwed.

Great now I'll go find some tin foil...